How do apps properly validate Face-id or biometrics before important actions on the backend?
I have a theoretical question, how is a mobile app supposed to handle Face-id or biometrics being required before certain task.
Let's say a banking app asks for Face ID on iPhone before making a transaction. How is the backend supposed to validate it? What is the backend supposed to get? Some sort of token? Can you provide me with any implementation guidelines on that?
Update: I get that the backend does not validate it. But what is the security standard in that case, reauthenticate the user?

"How is the backend supposed to validate it?" -- it doesn't. At least on Android, biometrics are simply a way to confirm that the person holding the phone is the authorized user of the phone. In that regard, it is no different than any other authentication mechanism (PIN, password, etc.). Biometrics may be quicker for the user, and so prompting the user to re-confirm their identity via biometrics is a nice safety check. But otherwise, your backend is working off of whatever sort of user tokens you would be using without biometrics.

Then what is the main recommendation for improved security before any crucial tasks?

Re-authenticate the user before crucial tasks. Biometrics is one mechanism for doing that, if the user has opted into that.

It's the same on iOS - Biometric authentication happens on the device.  An app can store a token in the Keychain and require device owner authentication (biometrics or passcode) to access it.  It is more secure that simply providing the token when the app is opened; It is some validation that the device owner has opened the app.  Biometric also can't be "shoulder surfed" and because they are typically fast, they can be used more often without annoying the user.

AUTHENTICATION
You could take a look at passkeys and the WebAuthn standard, where:

The main credential sent to the server is a digital signature produced with strong asymmetric cryptography.
The use of FaceID etc is a secondary authentication factor, mostly just to prove user presence and to help prevent automated attacks.

API ACCESS
Although a digital signature proves that the user authenticated, it can be useful if, after authentication, the app can also get an API credential for a high privilege business area.
Eg a banking app using OAuth 2.0 might operate like this:

The app triggers re-authentication with a parameter like scope=payments.
The authorization server presents passkey login forms to authenticate the user.
The authorization server issues an access token with the requested scope - and perhaps a level_of_assurance claim representing the user's authentication strength.
The API then has what it needs to decide whether to allow the high privilege operation.

SUMMARY
So there are a couple of backend concerns that you might separate:

Server side validation to verify a proof of the user identity
High privilege resource access afterwards

